# Error in create and reserve memory for struct array

Tags: c, arrays, struct

I have to create a function for read settings with this struct and format parameters (I can't change).

text file:

```
key1:value1
key2:value2
....
```

format:

```
typedef struct {
   char *key;
   char *value;

}configParam;

void loadSettings(char fileName[],configParam *paramsReaded[], int *length, int *statusCode);
```

and my code:

```
    void loadSettings(char fileName[],configParam *paramsReaded[], int *length, int *statusCode){
        *paramsReaded = (configParam*)malloc((*length)*sizeof(configParam));
        int j;
        for(j=0; j<*length; j++){
            *paramsReaded[j].key = (char *)malloc(MAX_STRING*sizeof(char));
            *paramsReaded[j].value = (char *)malloc(MAX_STRING*sizeof(char));
        }
    
        FILE *file = fopen(fileName,"rb");
        char line[100];
        char *token;
        int i,k;
        if (file == NULL){
            printf("\nError de lectura: archivo no encontrado\n");
            *statusCode = 0;
            exit(1);
        }
        while (feof(file) == 0){
            fgets(line,100,file);
            token = strtok(line,":");
            strcpy(*paramsReaded[i].key, token);
            token = strtok(NULL,":");
            strcpy(*paramsReaded[i].value, token);
            i++;
        }
        fclose(file);
    
        for(k=0; k<*length; k++){
        printf ("\nclave[%d]: %s \nvalor[%d]: %s\n",k , *paramsReaded[k].key,k , *paramsReaded[k].value);
        }
    
    }

int main(){
    
    char route[] = "settings_entrada.txt"; 
    int lengthSettings; 
    int statusCode = 1; // set in 0, if finds a error
    
    countLines(route,&lengthSettings); //only count lines of txt
    configParam parametersReaded[];
    
    loadSettings (route, &parametersReaded,&lengthSettings,&statusCode);
}
```

code::blocks shows me

> request for member '`key`' in something not a structure or union
>
> request for member '`value`' in something not a structure or union

I'm not sure if either declare the struct array `parametersReaded` :(

Comment: Try `(*paramsReaded)[j]` instead of `*paramsReaded[j]` and `(*paramsReaded)[i]` instead of `*paramsReaded[i]` and `(*paramsReaded)[k]` instead of `*paramsReaded[k]`

Comment: and `configParam parametersReaded[];` --> `configParam *parametersReaded;`

Comment: `while (feof(file) == 0){
            fgets(line,100,file);` --> `while (fgets(line,100,file)){`

Comment: Best to check the result of `strtok()` not being `NULL`.

Comment: Uninitialised `i` in `strcpy(*paramsReaded[i].key, token);` and again two lines later and in `i++`.

Comment: thanks all, missing the parentheses for the pointer  `*paramsReaded`